# unit test async/await code fails within the body of test

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, async-await

I am trying to write async/await unit test. I have tried ample of combos to make this test pass, but for some reason when the call happens it steps into the viewModel `checkNumber()`, executes the first two lines of code and thats it, it only works that way in test, not when I do integration test though. I need help to figure why the do block in my viewModel is being skipped by the test case that I am writing.

```
func test_checkNumber_success() async {
    let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "CheckNumber completes successfully")
    
    viewModel = PrimeNumberCheckViewModel(service: MockPrimeNumberService())
    
    XCTAssertEqual(viewModel.isPrime, false)
    XCTAssertEqual(viewModel.validationInProgress, false)
    
    let res = await viewModel.checkNumber(3)
    
    expectation.fulfill()
    
    XCTAssertEqual(viewModel.isPrime, true)
    XCTAssertEqual(viewModel.validationInProgress, false)
    
    wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 0.05) // Adjust the timeout as needed
}
```

```
final class PrimeNumberCheckViewModel: PrimeNumberCheckProtocol {
    @Published private(set) var validationInProgress =  false
    @Published var status = "checking ready to get started"
    @Published private(set)var isPrime: Bool = false
    
    private let service: PrimeServiceProtocol
    private var validationTask: Task<Void, Never>?
    
    init(service: PrimeServiceProtocol) {
        self.service = service
    }
    
    @MainActor
    func checkNumber(_ number: Int) async {

        self.validationInProgress = true
        self.status = "Checking \(number) in progress"
        
        validationTask?.cancel()
        
        validationTask = Task {
            var res = false

            do {
                res = try await service.checkNumber(number)
                print("this is res: \(res)")
                
                updateStatus(res, number)
                
                self.isPrime = res
            } catch {
                //TODO: handle error scenario case
                print(error)
            }
            self.validationInProgress = false
        }
    }
}
```

this is the service that I am injecting in my viewModel:

```
class MockPrimeNumberService: PrimeServiceProtocol {
    @MainActor
    func checkNumber(_ number: Int) async throws -> Bool {
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 2 * 1_000_000_000)
        
        // Check if the number is less than 2
        if number <= 1 {
            return false
        }
        
        // Check for divisibility from 2 to the square root of the number
        for i in 2..<Int(Double(number).squareRoot()) + 1 {
            if number % i == 0 {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: By assigning the Task to validationTask you are actually ignoring the “awaiting” part. Remove async from the function it is unnecessary there you have to choose if you want to await or not.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use an `XCTestExpectation` for this by the looks of it. This should work.

```
func test_checkNumber_success() async  {
        let viewModel = PrimeNumberCheckViewModel(service: MockPrimeNumberService())
        XCTAssertEqual(viewModel.isPrime, false)
        XCTAssertEqual(viewModel.validationInProgress, false)
        let res = await viewModel.checkNumber(3)
        XCTAssertEqual(viewModel.isPrime, true)
        XCTAssertEqual(viewModel.validationInProgress, false)
    }
```

It looks though like you're using a shared instance of your view model for every test, which might be leading to some unexpected state changes. I would recommend (and have in my answer above) creating a new instance for each test so that you can assert that a view model does very specific things without the risk of unexpected state changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1. As [Brandon said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77177913/1271826), you do not need expectations. You have an `async` test, so `await` is all you need.

   ```swift
   func testCheckNumber() async  {
       let viewModel = PrimeNumberCheckViewModel(service: MockPrimeNumberService())

       XCTAssertEqual(viewModel.isPrime, false)
       XCTAssertEqual(viewModel.validationInProgress, false)

       await viewModel.checkNumber(3)            // note, the view model method does not return anything

       XCTAssertEqual(viewModel.isPrime, true)
       XCTAssertEqual(viewModel.validationInProgress, false)
   }
   ```
2. You have marked your view model method as `async`, but it does not `await` anything. As a result, your test is calling a method that launches an asynchronous task, but does not `await` its completion. Thus the test is checking view model properties before they have a chance to be set.

   Add an `await validationTask?.result`.

   ```swift
   @MainActor
   func checkNumber(_ number: Int) async {
       validationTask?.cancel()

       status = "Checking \(number) in progress"
       validationInProgress = true

       validationTask = Task {
           defer { validationInProgress = false }

           do {
               let result = try await service.checkNumber(number)
               print("this is result: \(result)")

               updateStatus(result, number)

               isPrime = res
           } catch {
               //TODO: handle error scenario case
               print(error)
           }
       }

       await withTaskCancellationHandler {
           _ = await validationTask?.result
       } onCancel: {
           validationTask?.cancel()
       }
   }
   ```

   Note, if you really want to introduce [unstructured concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency#Unstructured-Concurrency), you bear responsibility for adding cancelation handling (e.g., `withTaskCancellationHandler`, as shown above), too.

Comment: that was the issue `await validationTask.value` also did  the job. thank you for helping solve this. or adding the @MainActor wrapper above the test function in the test class